# Moving app between appstore accounts

Tags: app-store

I have published an app that have sold pretty OK and i have since then started a company where i will do my development. I checked with Apple to change the name of my account but that seemed to be very complicated and time consuming.

The problem I have is that I would like to move this app to my new company and by that register a new account at iTunes Connect.

Does anyone know what the best strategy for this is as i do not want the current people that have bought the app to lose it.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't move apps between accounts.

The only reports of this being done are when a developer incorporates (and has all the paperwork to prove this), changes their developer account to a individual company enrollment, and then has their corporation get acquired by another company (with all the paperwork to prove such a corporate acquisition to Apple).

Best you can do otherwise is to delete the app from one account, and (re)submit it from another, which will involve changing the Bundle ID, and thus losing the app's previous customers, reviews, ratings, etc.

ADDED:
The above information is now obsolete.  In 2013, Apple added the capability to move apps (in normal status/states) between accounts in iTunes Connect, retaining users and reviews.

Comment: Here's a link to Apple's documentation about [Transferring Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)